# How to remove jquery ext for a div?

Tags: jquery, html

I have created below extension to achieve fixed header for table inside a div

```
$.fn.stickyHeader = function (options) {
        options = $.extend({
            setHeaderPercentage: false
        }, options);

        // this should be a div with overflow. we could traverse closest until we find one, but it's best if
        // this
        // is just used correctly.

        var $clone = this.find('table').clone();

        var id = $clone.attr('id') + '-stickyHeader';

        if (options.setHeaderPercentage) {
            var twidth = this.find('table').innerWidth();

            this.find('thead tr').each(function (i, o) {
                var $tr = $clone.find('thead tr').eq(i).find('th');
                var twidth = 0;

                $(o).find('th').each(function (i2, o2) {
                    twidth += $(o2).width();
                });

                $(o).find('th').each(function (i2, o2) {
                    var p = ($(o2).width() / twidth * 100);
                    $tr.eq(i2).css('width', p + '%');
                });
            });
        }

        $clone.find('tbody').remove();
        $clone = $('<div>').append($clone);

        $clone.css({
            'position': 'absolute',
            'top': '0',
            'left': '0',
            'right': '0',
            'margin-right': Cobalt.UI.Helpers.getScrollBarWidth() + 'px', // this will always have the margin even if the
            'display': 'block'
            // scrollbar isn't present
        });

        $clone.attr('id', id);

        var $container = $('<div>');

        $container.css({
            'margin': '0',
            'padding': '0',
            'border': '0',
            'font-size': '100%',
            'font': 'inherit',
            'vertical-align': 'baseline',
            'position': 'relative'
        });

        $container.insertBefore(this).append($clone).append(this);

        return this;
    };
```

I call this above extension as below:

//Sticky Header for profile list

```
$('#panel').stickyHeader();
```

My problem is that i need a mechanism to remove this extension at some point of time(some alternate condition), how can i achieve it?

**EDIT:** delete $.fn.stickyHeader; didnt worked out for my case...

Can we do something like the changes done inside the extension function will be reverted back using a simple logic???

Thanks in advance!!!

--
GOK

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
 delete $.fn.stickyHeader;
```

Comment: I think the OP means "unsticky" the header, not just deleting the method.

Comment: OK let me give it a try.. i meant unsticky not deleting

Comment: It didnt worked out.... how can i make the changes done inside the extension function such as clone and all to be reverted back??

Answer (score 0):

`$(#div).stickyHeader();` isn't actually a correct selector, I assume your intention is to apply it to all `div` tags, which would be `$('div').stickyHeader();`.

If that's the case, you could add a class or id to the div you don't want it on and use something like `$('div:not(#exclude)').stickyHeader();` to exclude it.

Comment: Yeah! My mistake.. its actually $('#panel').stickyHeader()... just i removed for the purpose of putting question